# Swift - Drag glitch while updating a label

Tags: ios, swift

I am tring to implement a draggable button (on x-asis) and it works fine with the code below:

The button that will be dragged is inside the mainButton (starting left aligned to it)

```
@IBAction func wasDragged(buttn: UIButton, event :UIEvent)
{
    var touch : UITouch = event.touchesForView(buttn)?.anyObject() as UITouch
    var previousLocation : CGPoint = touch.previousLocationInView(self.view)
    var location : CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    if buttn.frame.minX + delta_x > mainButton.frame.minX && buttn.frame.maxX + delta_x < mainButton.frame.maxX{
        buttn.center = CGPointMake(buttn.center.x + delta_x,buttn.center.y)
    }
}
```

But, when i add a line to update another label on screen as below into this function, the button starts to glitch as the label gets updated

```
@IBAction func wasDragged(buttn: UIButton, event :UIEvent)
{
    var touch : UITouch = event.touchesForView(buttn)?.anyObject() as UITouch
    var previousLocation : CGPoint = touch.previousLocationInView(self.view)
    var location : CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    var delta_x :CGFloat = location.x - previousLocation.x
    if buttn.frame.minX + delta_x > mainButton.frame.minX && buttn.frame.maxX + delta_x < mainButton.frame.maxX{
        buttn.center = CGPointMake(buttn.center.x + delta_x,buttn.center.y)

        self.statusLabel.text = "Time left:(\(timeLeft))!"
    }
}
```

Any ideas about how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is glitching because when you update the label, *Auto Layout* is running and putting your button back to where its constraints say it should be.  You shouldn't be updating the button's frame when using *Auto Layout*.

Instead, in *Interface Builder* add a constraint to position your button relative to the leading edge of its superview.  Then add an `IBOutlet` to this constraint by <kbd>Control</kbd>-dragging from the constraint (you can find it in the *Document Outline* view) to the code.  Give it a name like `buttonH`.

Then in your code, update the `constant` property of the constraint to move the button:

```
buttonH.constant += delta_x
```

Comment: Just did as you suggested but again used Horizontal Alignments constant property to update, keeping the button at the same position. Thank you...